# What are the Component Object Model(COM) style behaviors/restrictions exhibited by WinRT types

Tags: c#, com, windows-runtime

As we all know that WinRT is an enhanced version of Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM). I didn't get much chance to work directly with COM components except to manage distributed transactions over a decade ago. I'm sure COM is used a lot internally at OS level.

I was reading that WinRT types are subject to COM-style restrictions. I was able to get few restrictions by searching over internet as below:

- WinRT types have to be sealed by default as asked in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492132/why-do-winrt-types-have-to-be-sealed).
- they offer limited support for inheritance and generics in the sense that it only supports interface inheritance but not implementation inheritance as suggested in the accepted answer in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493865/why-exposed-types-must-be-sealed-for-winmd-winrt-components).

Can someone help me with some good high level restrictions imposed for COM types or may be point me to some good resource where I can get an exhaustive information on this. I tried googling a lot but to no help.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Restriction and Rules part of Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime)

> Since Windows Runtime is projected to various languages, some
> restrictions on fundamental data types exist so as to host all such
> languages. Programmers must be careful with the behavior of those
> types when used with public access (for method parameters, method
> return values, properties, etc.
>
> **Basic types**
>
> In .NET languages and C++, a rich set of data types exists,
> representing various numerals.
>
> In JavaScript, a Number can only represent up to 53 bits of precision.
>
> In WinRT, the only lacking numeral data type is 8-bit signed integer
> relative to .NET and C++. JavaScript developers must be careful when
> dealing with big numbers while coding for WinRT.
>
> **Strings**
>
> Strings are immutable in .NET and JavaScript, but mutable in C++.
>
> A null pointer passed as a string to WinRT by C++ is converted to an
> empty string
>
> In .Net, null being passed as a string to WinRT is converted to an
> empty string
>
> In JavaScript, null being passed as a string to WinRT is converted to
> a string with the word null. This is due to JavaScript's keyword null
> being represented as a null object
>
> Similar results occur when passing undefined to WinRT from JavaScript
>
> **Structs**
>
> In .NET and C++, structs are value types, and such a struct can
> contain any type in it.
>
> JavaScript does not directly support structs.
>
> In WinRT, use of structs is allowed only for containing types that
> have value semantics, including numerals, strings, and other structs.
> Pointers or interface references are disallowed.
>
> **References**
>
> In .NET, objects are passed by reference, whereas numerals and structs are >passed by value.
>
> In C++, all types can be passed by reference or value.
>
> In WinRT, interfaces are passed by reference; all other types are
> passed by value.
>
> **Arrays**
>
> In .NET, C++, and JavaScript arrays are reference types.
>
> In WinRT, arrays are value types.
>
> **Events**
>
> In .NET and C++, clients subscribe to events using += operator.
>
> In JavaScript, addEventListener function or setting on
> property is used to subscribe to events.
>
> In WinRT, all languages can use their own way to subscribe to events.
>
> **Collections**
>
> Some .NET collections map directly to WinRT collections.
>
> WinRT Vector type resembles arrays and the array syntax is used to
> consume them.
>
> WinRT Map type is a key/value pair collection, and is projected as
> Dictionary in .NET languages.
>
> **Method overloading**
>
> All WinRT languages (.NET, C++, JavaScript) support overloading on
> parameters
>
> .NET and C++ also support overloading on type.
>
> In WinRT, only parameter number is used for overloading.
>
> **Asynchrony**
>
> All WinRT methods are designed such that any method taking longer than
> 50 milliseconds is an async method.
>
> The established naming pattern to distinguish asynchronous methods is
> Async. For the full runtime library, all methods that have a chance to
> last longer than 50 ms are implemented as asynchronous methods only.